# Comparing and sorting strings

Tags: java, string, sorting

I have to make a program where there is a class of Students. I need to make an array of Students, then I need to sort the students by name.  I'm not sure how do do it.  This is the code I have.

```
 public void selectionSort(ArrayList<Student> arr){

        int i, j;
        Student temp;
        for(i = 0; i < arr.size()-1; i++){
            for(j = i + 1; j <arr.size(); j++){
                if(arr.get(j).getName() < arr.get(i).getName()){
                    {
                        temp =arr.get(j);
                        arr.set(j, arr.get(i));
                        arr.set(i, temp);
            }
          }
        }

      }
```

Edits:

Yes, this is for homework.  It doesn't matter if I use an Array or an ArrayList, but I'm not allowed to use Collections.sort.  The class implements comparison.

Comment: Create object inside loop `Student temp =arr.get(j);`

Comment: You're passing an ArrayList of students, not an array

Comment: If you are really using an ArrayList and not an array, Collections.sort(...) with an appropriate Comparator should do the trick. Similarly, if it *is* an array, you can always choose Arrays.sort(...). That is, if you just want your datastructure sorted, not necessarily by doing it manually.

Comment: And if you're using ArrayList when the assignment specifically demands an array, you're going to lose points. You should review your materials.

Comment: From the code you posted, it appears that you are trying to sort the list of students using a [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Is this a homework exercise? Do you have to implement bubble sort? Do you have any other limitations, or can you use anything in the API of the JDK?